# Keeping a settings file in a Web Application

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, configuration-files

Are there any recommendations on how to keep an application level settings/configuration file in a J2EE project? I have a web project that has dependences that must write to the logs, and a local settings file. Is there anyway to store the settings file in the local directory and have it writable?

[Some of the dependencies are: hibernate and gridgain, so they produce a lot of logs]

I would rather not hard code the location of the settings file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the configuration files under the `WEB-INF` folder. You could create a directory `/WEB-INF/config`. If they should be in the classpath put them to `/WEB-INF/classes`. By doing it this way, the location is not hardcoded, but at a well known place for your application.

Putting them inside `/WEB-INF` is important, so the files are not "accessible" by the browser.

---

Another way could be to add a parameter to the `web.xml` configuration, where you specify the location of your configuration files so they are not inside the webapps directory. You could do this by adding a `context-param`. For example:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>configuration</param-name>
    <param-value>/var/myapp/config</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The value will be made visible to your web application as a servlet context initialization parameter named **configuration**. You can then use it as a base path to read your configuration files (Get the value by calling the `getInitParameter` method from the `ServletContext`).

But this will only work for config files, which are not needed in the classpath.

Comment: That doesn't bother me. The logs end up going to the tomcat logs folder [which doesn't bother me]

Comment: Is the Web-INF compiled into the war or is that outside the war?

Comment: If it is compiled in to the WAR I need a way to have it outside of the application.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the path to the configuration files to the webapp's **classpath**. That's the common approach and many API's are also designed to load the configuration from the classpath. For the case you're loading those files manually, you can use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` to get an `InputStream` of the classpath resource.

First, create a fixed path somewhere outside the webapp directory to drop the configurationfiles in, e.g. `/var/webapp/config`. Then configure the servletcontainer to include this path in the classpath. In case of Tomcat, you can specify it in the `shared.loader` or `common.loader` property of the `/conf/catalina.properties` file.

Comment: If your are doing it this way, the configuration files are visible to all installed webapps. If you have only one webapp, that's okay, otherwise this could be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Soundlink.

You also could store your setting in **database**. When your servlet starts up, the setting data should be loaded from database.

- pro: No need to maintain
  configuration files which are not Java EE
  standard.
- con: It works after servlet starts
  up.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it requires for you to have a specific set of tables in the database, and or a database for the application. The database I'm working with is already quite large. Setting files make the web app abit easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping settings in database is better as the application needs to support clustering